# Facebook chat plugin: is there is a way to add friends-only option for the fb:live-stream plug in?

Tags: facebook, plugins

I wonder if there is a way to add friends-only option for the fb:live-stream plug in?
It was mentioned here https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/258/  and I see a screenshot over here http://www.fbhive.com/facebook-releases-live-stream-box-allows-real-time-user-updates-for-live-events  but can't find how to do anymore.. was this option deprecated??

many thanks in advance for your help..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not a way to view the Live Stream plugin with friends-only. We removed this option with the update of the plugin on September 27, 2010 (http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/412/).

Comment: Thanks guys.. it's unfortunate, of course.  A quick follow up question: is there a way to configure the widget not to have "Post to Facebook" check-box checked by default?